# What happened to the dwarves in Erebor during Lord of the Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

I know Moria was retaken by Balrog, but what happened to Erebor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is assumed that the dwarves mainly dwelt in their mountains in the North enjoying their riches. In the Fellowship of the Ring (Movie), Elrond says:

> Our allies are lessening. Who will we call to. Dwarves? They hide in their mountains and care nothing for the matters of men.

Even though it is from the movie, it still is true to the book. There are no mentions of dwarves being involved in the War of the Ring, and Gimli is be an exception. The account of the dwarves is very small at the time of Lord of the Rings.

Comment: Sauron attacked Erebor during the War of the Ring, they were involved.

Comment: Hmm I don't recall that, it's been a year and a half since reading LOTR, I guess I need a refresher (which is why I'm rereading it).